# Regular Expression to find entire link in string

Tags: java, regex, url, expression, apex

I have a regular expression in apex that is only grabbing part of the link I need in a string. I need it to grab the entire link.

Here is what im working with:

```
String myvar = 'this is an example http://test.com/testing/123654123%0A%0A%0A%';

String myvar1 = '(?:(?:(?:[a-z0-9]{3,9}:(?://)?)(?:[-;:&=+$,w]+@)?[a-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=+$??,w]+@)[a-z0-9.-]+)((?:/[+~%/.w-]*)?\\??(?:[-+=&;%@.w]*)#?w*)?)';

            Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile(myvar1);

            Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(myvar);

            while (MyMatcher.find()) { 
                System.debug(MyMatcher.group());
                Location = MyMatcher.group();
        }
```

This is only returning http://test.com/

I need http://test.com/testing/123654123

How can I modify the regular expression to provide the complete link?

I just need to modify my existing regex to accomplish this. How can keep as much of the regular expression im using as possible?

```
(?:(?:(?:[a-z0-9]{3,9}:(?://)?)(?:[-;:&=+$,w]+@)?[a-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=+$??,w]+@)[a-z0-9.-]+)((?:/[+~%/.w-]*)?\\??(?:[-+=&;%@.w]*)#?w*)?)
```

Comment: If you are just trying to match the links then won't `http[^\\s]+` be suffice ? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iS4zW4/1)

Comment: which kind of links ? only HTTP or do you need it to get any kind of links ? (https:// gopher:// ftp:// myownpersonnalurlscheme://)  do you need to split the different components, do you need to handle ports and users etc.

Comment: There is no real reliable ways to find urls in a string. All you can do is to search a defined kind of urls.

Comment: Hello the link is followed by %'s in my actual version. How would i fix that? For example this is an example test.com/testing/123654123%0A%0A%0A%

Comment: @noob can you please help me?

Comment: @Niche: I deleted my answer because there was no particular delimiter in your link to stop matching. I will think on it later on. Please try formatting question more clearly and add some more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex :

```
https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.\/-]*
```

Online demo http://regexr.com/3d7j7